# Chrome Extensions or Software to download all the webpages?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

There is a blog (wordpress) I really like and I would like to download all the webpages and save it on my PC.

Blog is NOTthat big, only couple of articles.

Is there a Chrome Extensions addon be able to do this?

Comment: I really like the title.

Comment: @Eroen, well it is a meme…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a Chrome extension, but running [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) with the `-r` switch would download all the pages from the blog. By default it only limits the downloads  to the same hostname, but this can be configured.

If the blog is hosted on a shared service (with an url like `example.bloghost.com/`) you might want to use the `-D example.bloghost.com` option, or if it's like `bloghost.com/example` you might want the `-I /example/` option.

Example:

```
wget -r example.com
```

Comment: Note, this solution is easy, but it comes with a big problem in practice on most sites: if you have a page located at `/foo` and one at `/foo/bar`, then only one of them can be saved, as you can't have both a file and directory in the same folder with the same name. You will have to manually rename all the index pages to `*/index.htm` and then run `wget` again.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com). It downloaded all files, then you can access them offline.

> HTTrack is a free (GPL, libre/free software) and easy-to-use offline
>   browser utility.
>
> It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a
>   local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML,
>   images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack
>   arranges the original site's relative link-structure. Simply open a
>   page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and you can browse the
>   site from link to link, as if you were viewing it online. HTTrack can
>   also update an existing mirrored site, and resume interrupted
>   downloads. HTTrack is fully configurable, and has an integrated help
>   system.
>
> WinHTTrack is the Windows 2000/XP/Vista/Seven release of HTTrack, and
>   WebHTTrack the Linux/Unix/BSD release.

Comment: What if the server needs first an authorised session to be open? There is a browser extension for this?